# Sub-(complete lattice)? - what's the correct terminology?

Tags: terminology, order-theory, lattice-orders

Let $X$ denote a set, let $\mathcal{O}$ denote the open sets of a topological space with carrier $X$, and let $\mathcal{P}$ denote the powerset of $X$. Furthermore, let $\leq_\mathcal{O}$ denote the restriction of $\subseteq$ to $\mathcal{O}$, and let $\leq_\mathcal{P}$ denote the restriction of $\subseteq$ to $\mathcal{P}$.

Then $(\mathcal{O},\leq_\mathcal{O})$ is a sublattice of $(\mathcal{P},\leq_\mathcal{P})$

Thus, since $(\mathcal{O},\leq_\mathcal{O})$ is complete when viewed as a lattice, I feel it would be appropriate to say "$(\mathcal{O},\leq_\mathcal{O})$ is a complete sublattice of $(\mathcal{P},\leq_\mathcal{P})."$ Is this how the statement would usually be phrased?

Similarly, since the induced meet operations $\bigwedge_\mathcal{O}$ and $\bigwedge_\mathcal{P}$ don't agree, I think it would be appropriate to say "its not the case that $(\mathcal{O},\leq_\mathcal{O})$ is a "sub-(complete lattice)" of $(\mathcal{P},\leq_\mathcal{P})."$ Is this how the statement would usually be phrased? Is there perhaps a better way of saying it?

Answer (score 2):

The *best* way of saying it is this: $\mathcal{O}$ is a **subframe** of $\mathcal{P}$. Here is the general definition:

A **frame** is a partially ordered set $F$ that has joins for all subsets, meets for all finite subsets, and in which finite meets distribute over all joins. A **subframe** of $F$ is a subset $F' \subseteq F$ such that $F'$ is closed in $F$ under joins for all subsets of $F'$ and $F'$ is closed in $F$ under meets for all finite subsets of $F'$.

I think the usual understanding of the phrase ‘complete sublattice’ is that the subset is closed under joins *and* meets for all subsets, i.e. what you might call a ‘sub-(complete lattice)’. Following this pattern, you can say that $\mathcal{O}$ is a complete join sub-semilattice of $\mathcal{P}$. But this terminology is potentially confusing, as you have observed.

Comment: Zhen, the first part of your answer is mistaken. A frame (or "complete Heyting Algebra") is a complete lattice in which finite meets distribute over arbitrary joins. And $(\mathcal{O},\leq_\mathcal{O})$ is not necessarily a subframe of $(\mathcal{P},\leq_\mathcal{P}),$ because infinite meets needn't coincide.

Comment: Anyway, the issue is that, for example: a sublattice is more than just a subposet that happens to be a lattice. The join and meet operations also need to coincide. Similarly, a complete sublattice and a sub-(complete lattice) are different, although I'm unsure of whether this is standard terminology.

Comment: Oh, and note that if a poset is closed under arbitrary meets, then it is necessarily closed under arbitrary joins as well. And vice versa.

Comment: No: the data of a frame only includes finite meets and possibly-infinite joins, so to be a subframe, you only need to have the same finite meets and possibly-infinite joins. Saying that a poset is "closed" under [operation] is bad terminology: it suggests there is an absolute notion of [operation] in some universal poset, and this is not the case. So a subposet of a frame that is closed under joins need not be closed under meets: it will have meets, but they won't be the same in general.

Comment: Along similar lines, it is very bad form to conflate frames and complete Heyting algebras. The data of a complete Heyting algebra includes the Heyting operation, which automatically exists in any frame, but a frame homomorphism need not preserve the Heyting operation.

Comment: Hmmm. Well I am going by the definitions [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frames_and_locales), so I think we're using different definitions. And yes, you're right about the use of the term "closed," I should really have said, "If a poset admits arbitrary meets, then it admits arbitrary joins, too."

Comment: So what you're saying is, while it would be incorrect to say that $(\mathcal{O},\leq_\mathcal{O})$ is a sub-(complete Heyting algebra) of $(\mathcal{P},\leq_\mathcal{P}),$ it would be correct to say that $(\mathcal{O},\leq_\mathcal{O})$ is a subframe of $(\mathcal{P},\leq_\mathcal{P}).$ Because frame monomorphisms are different from complete Heyting algebra monomorphisms. Is this what you're getting at?

Comment: That's right: frame homomorphisms are not the same as homomorphisms of complete Heyting algebras.